# Java DateTimeFormatter adding a Z when timezone is +0000

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

Let's say I have two dates:´

- 20191105235900
- 20190802235900

I use dateTimeFormatter with `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.getDefault());`

In the end I obtain this:

- 2019-11-05T23:59:00Z - wrong, correct would be 2019-11-05T23:59:00+00:00
- 2019-08-02T23:59:00+01:00 - correct

Also I can't just replace the Z with +00:00 as that would be one more processing step.

Full code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.getDefault());
this.timestampString = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: When you say "wrong" - it's behaving exactly as documented: "For formatting, if the offset value from GMT is 0, "Z" is produced." I suspect you could more easily fix this if you could move to using `java.time` though.

Comment: "Also I can't just replace the Z with +00:00 as that would be one more processing step." Could you explain why adding "one more processing step" is infeasible?

Comment: It produces `2019-11-05` and you want it to be `2019-08-02`, a totally different date. What is the reasoning behind that? And I don't see why one of those input dates should produce +01:00, and the other +00:00.

Comment: @Amongalen Fixed, my bad. Also, me neither but apparently that's what it does.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's an issue involving literally billions of entries. Every step counts.

Comment: "And I don't see why one of those input dates should produce +01:00, and the other +00:00" - presumably because the system default time zone is UTC+0 in November 2019 and UTC+1 in August 2019. That would be the case in the UK, for example.

Comment: @BryceSoker: That should be part of the question then - ideally with some benchmark evidence that you've tried it but that it's prohibitively expensive. If performance is so massively important for this task, I doubt that just using the default locale is the best approach either. I'd also be interested in how the performance changes if you use java.time formatting instead.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Your ISO 8601 format is built in, `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` gives it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at [the Wikipedia Page for ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) you will find that this is the expected behavior:

> **Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)**
>
> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".
>
> The Z suffix in the ISO 8601 time representation is sometimes referred to as "Zulu time" because the same letter is used to designate the Zulu time zone. However the ACP 121 standard that defines the list of military time zones makes no mention of UTC and derives the "Zulu time" from the Greenwich Mean Time[28] which was formerly used as the international civil time standard. GMT is no longer precisely defined by the scientific community and can refer to either UTC or UT1 depending on context.[29]

Any client should be able to parse that.

Comment: It's also explicitly documented behaviour for SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Yeah, because SimpleDateFormat will return an ISO8601 formatted string. I hoped it would benefit the OP to know why it basically has to be like this and why they can expect standard conforming clients to parse this without a problem.